# Node.js - performance.now is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance.now

I have a Node.js app. When I run `node -v` from the command-line, I see the following:

v10.3.0

This is relevant because I'm interested in using the [Performance Hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html). I've created the most basic thing I can think of, which looks like this in an in a file named 'index.js':

```
const performance = require('perf_hooks');

let p = performance.now();
```

When I run `node index.js` from the command-line, I get an error that says:

*TypeError: performance.now is not a function*

Why am I getting this error? What am I missing?

Comment: try `const {performance} = require('perf_hooks');`

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_examples

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `perf_hooks` module exports several things, one of them is `performance`, so using object destructuring you could do:

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');
```

Or with object access:

```
const performance = require('perf_hooks').performance;
```