# How do I use performance.now()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I would like to use performance.now() as seen in the top answer to this SO Post.

[How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute/15641427#15641427)

However is it was not available in my Replit or my local Node server.

Do I have to install it?

I searched packages on Repl.it and this came up

[image]

In the repl.it I added ...

const performance = require('performance');
const t0 = performance.now();

and it auto installed performance but I am still getting an error ... now it is saying that now() is not a function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - performance.now is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646279/node-js-performance-now-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 5):

It's part of the browser's javascript API, no 3rd party is needed.

From MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now:

> The returned value represents the time elapsed since the time origin.

Usage example:

```js
const t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
const t1 = performance.now();
console.log(`Call to doSomething took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds.`);
```

Answer (score 0):

no installation it's part of the node api. Your best answer, by far, will be to look at the thorough documentation here - https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html.